# Display an extra text message in LLVM .ll IR

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I need to display an additional text message in the .ll file of a sample cpp code that is displayed when -S -emit-llvm is used but not when $ clang++ code.cpp -o code.out && ./code.out is used.
How do I do it?
The extra text message should be of the below form in the .ll file:
<<<<===================IR code=======================>>>>

EXTRA information

<<<<<==================IR code========================>>>>

Example:

<<<<===================IR code=================================>>>>

EXTRA :: LLVM is so cool

<<<<<==================IR code=================================>>>>

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/fnord), is that what it is?

Comment: Do you mean a comment or just any generic code which is not part of the LLVM standard?